# Realtime Exchange Rate Data API

Tags: programming, fx

There are various sources for real-time exchange rate data, e.g. [Ariva EUR/USD](http://www.ariva.de/euro-dollar-kurs/push-chart?boerse_id=130).

Is there also an API or other source which enables to automatically retrieve real-time exchange rates as a data stream e.g. for a trading tool (e.g. in Excel/C#)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the spread betting firms in the UK (IG Index) has an API freely available (at https://labs.ig.com/) that provides streaming FX rates.

You need an account to access the API, but you can sign-up for free and start using the API. They have a C# SDK available so you should be able to get up and running quite quickly.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Bloomberg's programmable plugin will do this.
So will Reuters or Activ Tick or any other number of manage data brokers.

All it involves is signing a contract and paying.

I think you'll need to flesh out your question a bit more to get a more detailed answer.

Interactive brokers does offer a fair bit of data in "real time", assume its a few seconds delayed due to receiving it over the internet.  I'm guessing they probably throttle their feeds to around a max of 2 quote changes per second per symbol.

> Is there also an API or other source which enables to automatically retrieve real-time exchange rates as a data stream e.g. for a trading tool (e.g. in Excel/C#)?

This might just be a terminology issue but you probably want your real time data to stream to you not be retrieved as that implies polling.

Comment: Yes I think your answer is close, can you also find a free real-time exchange rate data source?

Comment: I don't know of any.  Interactive brokers is pretty good about giving out data as long as you trade with them.  Does that count as free?

Comment: @emcor  Each exchange usually makes a few days of sample data available, Exchange data usually sells for anywhere from $3000-$10,000 per year so you won't get it for free.  See here for NYSE sample data and formats http://www.nyxdata.com/Data-Products/Daily-TAQ

Answer (score 1):

Your options for real-time tick data are limited, but there are some:

- Limited pairs, multiple updates per minute (HTML format) -
  http://webrates.truefx.com/rates/connect.html?f=html
- The only reliable/free JSON API: http://1forge.com/forex-data-api

Answer (score -1):

Interactivebrokers is also an excellent platform thats been around for ages, and has api interfacing

Comment: Does it have FX realt-time data?

Comment: yes it does                                .                     .

Comment: Is it free?____

Comment: as i recall , it is.  afterall, there is no stock exchange involved that would have fees